# Reference for proof that the circumcenter of an acute triangle lies in the inside

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I have seen the statement that in an acute triangle the circumcenter lies inside the triangle. However I am unable to find a proof.

Is there a reference you can recommend where I can find a rigorous proof?

Comment: It is related to the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem)

Comment: Though for a rigorous proof, you will need a definition of "inside", possibly based on "betweenness".  I am not sure Euclid had one.

Comment: Everything I've ever seen rests on the inscribed angle theorems of Book III of Elements. Coxeter covers the possibilities as examples or exercises in the first chapters of his introductory books on geometry.